# Pandas: dynamically add rows before & after groups

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a Pandas data frame:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={"Value": [5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 2, 7, 0], "Group": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})

   Value  Group
0    5.0      1
1    0.0      1
2    0.0      1
3    8.0      1
4    0.0      2
5    3.0      2
6    0.0      2
7    2.0      2
8    7.0      2
9    0.0      2
```

Also I calculated the cumulative sum with respect to two rows for each group:

```
{"2-cumsum Group 1": array([5., 8.]), "2-cumsum Group 2": array([7., 5.])}
```

E.g. `array([5., 8.])` because `array([5.0, 0.0])` (rows 0 and 1) `+ array([0.0 + 8.0])` (rows 2 and 3) `= array([5., 8.])`.

What I now need is to append exactly two rows at the beginning of `df`, in-between each group and at the end of `df` so that I get the following data frame (gaps are for illustration purposes):

```
    Value  Group
0    10.0      0    # Initialize with 10.0
1    10.0      0    # Initialize with 10.0

2     5.0      1 
3     0.0      1
4     0.0      1
5     8.0      1

6     5.0      0    # 5.0 ("2-cumsum Group 1"[0])
7     2.0      0    # 8.0 ("2-cumsum Group 1"[1])

8     0.0      2
9     3.0      2
10    0.0      2
11    2.0      2
12    7.0      2
13    0.0      2

14    7.0      0    # 5.0 ("2-cumsum Group 2"[0])
15    5.0      0    # 8.0 ("2-cumsum Group 2"[1])
```

Please consider that the original data frame is much larger, has more than just two columns and I need to dynamically append rows with varying entries. E.g. the rows to append should have an additional column with "10.0" entries. Also, calculating the cumulative sum with respect to some integer (in this case 2) is variable (could be 8).

There are so many occasions where I need to generate rows based on other rows in data frames but I didn't find any effective solutions other than using for-loops and some temporary cache lists that save values from previous iterations.
I would appreciate some help.
Thank you in advance and kind regards.

---

My original code applied to the exemplary data, in case anybody needs it. It's very confusing and ineffective so only consider it if you really need to:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Some stuff
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Group1": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
                        "Group2": [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                       "Group3": [1, 9, 2, 1, 1],
                       "Value": [5, 8, 3, 2, 7]})

length = 2
max_value = 20

g = df['Group1'].unique()
h = df["Group2"].unique()
i = range(1,df['Group3'].max()+1)

df2 = df.set_index(['Group1','Group2','Group3']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([g,h,i])).assign(cc = lambda x: (x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())//length).rename_axis(['Group1','Group2','Group3'],axis=0)
df2 = df2.loc[~df2['Value'].isna().groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0),df2['cc']]).transform('all')].reset_index().fillna(0).drop('cc',axis=1)

values = df2["Value"].copy().to_numpy()
values = np.array_split(values, len(values)/length) 
stock = df2["Group1"].copy().to_numpy() 
stock = np.array_split(stock, len(stock)/length)

# Generate the "Group" column and generate the "2-cumsum" arrays 
# stored in the "volumes" variable
k = 0
a_groups = []
values_cache = []
volumes = []
for e, i in enumerate(values):
        if any(stock[e] == stock[e-1]):
            if np.any(i + values_cache >= max_value):
                k += 1
                volumes.append(values_cache)
                values_cache = i
            else:
                values_cache += i
            a_groups.extend([k] * length)
        else:
            k += 1
            if e:
                volumes.append(values_cache)
            values_cache = i
            a_groups.extend([k] * length)
volumes.append(values_cache)
df2["Group"] = a_groups

print(df2[["Value", "Group"]])
print("\n")
print(f"2-cumsums: {volumes}")

"""Output

   Value  Group
0    5.0      1
1    0.0      1
2    0.0      1
3    8.0      1
4    0.0      2
5    3.0      2
6    0.0      2
7    2.0      2
8    7.0      2
9    0.0      2

2-cumsums: [array([5., 8.]), array([7., 5.])]"""
```

Comment: "_Also I calculated the cumulative sum with respect to two rows for each group_" How did you do that? It'd be helpful if you shared your attempts and previous work so that the people volunteering to answer this question for you didn't have to recreate anything from scratch

Comment: @PaulH I can share my code but it would only confuse everybody. It's not very effective but does the job. Please refresh the website to see the changes.

Comment: The expected output for group 2 seems incorrect

Comment: @PaulH What do you mean? If I run the code it works fine. Also I just added two lines to the posted code just so you know.

Comment: I would expect "2-cumsum Group 2"[0] to be 0 + 3 = 3 and "2-cumsum Group 2"[1] to be 0 + 2 = 2

Comment: @PaulH I tried to make this clear but I didn't have the words for it. It doesn't sum up inside of the two rows but it packs two rows into one array of size 2 and then adds all the resulting arrays from within one group together. E.g. `"[5, 0] + [0, 8] = [5, 8]"`

Comment: * I'll be unavailable for ~ 1 h unfortunately and will make sure to answer afterwards.